# can not using git to add directory recursively?

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to add one directory and all files in it to git repo, after doing 
`git add "AppDir"`, 
then run `git status`, it still display "modified content, untracked content", like below, is that normal behavior?

running `git commit -a` also not helping.

below is the detail of `git status`:

```
bogon:AppDir springrider$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   AppDir (modified content, untracked content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: `git commit -a` won't add new files. But `git add dir` should work.

Comment: @svick: not in this case - the OP has already done that.  The `(modified content, untracked content)` message in status is distinctive and is only shown for submodules / gitlinks.

Comment: @MarkLongair, ah, I didn't recognize the message, so I just assumed it's different version of git. This explains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `AppDir` is a git repository itself - you've staged a so-called "gitlink" to that repository.  The output of `git status` is now telling you that *within the `AppDir` repository* there are untracked files and modified content.

If you really intended to do this, it's probably better to add that repository as a [submodule](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html), rather than just a plain gitlink.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally misunderstood the message.